# Windows Form, display indicator over a dynamically generated bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I have a usercontrol that displays a gradient of colors which, once created will be constant.

The usercontrol doesn't contain any controls, not sure if i need to add a picturebox or dynamically add one.

Over that image, I'd like to display a line that will display what the current result is. I have no problem creating the gradient image on the map, however I'd like to somehow cache it so everytime I update the indicator (call CurrentValue from parent form), it will put the indicator line above the gradient image.  This is updating about 30 times a second, thus, as of how the code below is working, it's repainting the gradient everytime, which is flickering.

Here's a code sample:

```
namespace Maps.UserControls
{
    public partial class UserControlLegend : UserControl
    {
        private double m_CurrentValue;
        public double CurrentValue
        {
            get
            {
                return m_CurrentValue;
            }
            set
            {
                m_CurrentValue = value;
                RefreshValue();
            }
        }

        public UserControlLegend()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControlLegend_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (b == null)
            {
                g = e.Graphics;
                b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(menuWidth, menuHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                // Code here that draws Menu

                // Cache bitmap here?
                g.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void RefreshValue()
        {
            this.Refresh();
            g = this.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0);
            //Code to Calcuate current Indicator Location

            int x3 = 0;
            // Draws current indicator correctly
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black)), this.Width / 2 - 15, x3, this.Width / 2 - 5, x3);
            g.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out.  I drew the bitmap and just used another control for the indicator, then just moved the location to point to where I wanted it.  Works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained above in comments, used a bitmap, and just set the x,y of the control.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest you set your Control's property `DoubleBuffered` to `True`, so that flickering goes away. However, if you don't draw on the Control itself, that will be not useful at all. Drawing on a `PictureBox` is better, however, becuase it is automatically `DoubleBuffered`.

Second, you are painting into a new `Bitmap` every time, which is very bad in terms of memory, since the `Bitmap` is a few megabytes in size. I'd suggest you have a single `Bitmap` initialized in the constructor, and a single `Graphics`, created from that `Bitmap` in the constructor, too. Every time the `paint` accurs, just clear the old `Graphics g` and then draw onto it again and again. `g Graphics` and `b Bitmap` should be `Dispose`d one time only, when the entire Control is `Dispose`d.

This may inhance your code.